# How to load Symfony's config parameters from database (Doctrine)

Tags: php, symfony

Instead of hard coding the parameters in `parameters.yml` I am trying to load them from database. Not all parameters in parameters.yml needs to be loaded from database just a few, like api details of paypal

In `config.yml` I have imported the `parameters.php`

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.php }
```

If I add static information in `parameters.php` like the one below it works fine

```
$demoName = 'First Last';
$container->setParameter('demoName', $demoName);
```

However I am not able to fetch information from database table. I thought i should create class and make use of `$em = this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` and it should work but it doesn't and i get the error of

`Notice: Undefined variable: paypal_data in /opt/lampp/htdocs/services/app/config/parameters.php (which is being imported from "/opt/lampp/htdocs/services/app/config/config.yml").`

This is the attempt i made is as following but the code does not seem to go in `__construct()`

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class parameters extends Controller
{
    public $paypal_data;

    function __construct() {
        $this->indexAction();
    }

    public function indexAction(){

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $this->paypal_data = $em->getRepository('featureBundle:paymentGateways')->findAll();

    }

}
$demoName = 'First Last';
$container->setParameter('demoName', $demoName);
$container->setParameter('paypal_data', $this->paypal_data);
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tryed to set $paypal_data as class scope as `$this-paypal_data`?

Comment: yes i tried that as well

Comment: Maybe you need to instanciate the parameters object ?

Comment: This most definitely will not work. Controllers are for converting a request to a response, not for using just anywhere where you want some logic. You can't use any service in the parsing of configuration, at this stage you are still configuring the container, you can't use it yet. You also have some misconceptions about OO in PHP.

Comment: @Gerry so what do i have to do to use it then? can you elaborate your point more? why cant i create a simple parameter class and fetch data from database?

Comment: You could query the database, but you certainly can't use the doctrine service to do so. You could set up a plain PDO connection and manually query. That said, you probably should go for an entirely different approach, why not get the data when you need it (and only then), instead of querying it in the container configuration? How do you intend to use this parameter?

Comment: well i am sure i am not trying to achieve something that has not been done before. all i am trying to do is rather than hard coding the paypal credentials in config.yml, simply allow user to define them in admin panel and whatever value user has defined use them in config.yml

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are doing wrong things. You need to declare your CompilerPass and add it to the container. After whole container will be loaded... in the compile time you will have access to all services in it.

Just get the entity manager service and query for needed parameters and register them in container.

**Step-by-step instruction:**

- Define Compiler pass:

  ```
  # src/Acme/YourBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ParametersCompilerPass.php
  class ParametersCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
  {
      public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
      {
          $em = $container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
          $paypal_params = $em->getRepository('featureBundle:paymentGateways')->findAll();
          $container->setParameter('paypal_data', $paypal_params);
      }
  }
  ```
- In the bundle definition class you need to add compiler pass to your container

  ```
  # src/Acme/YourBundle/AcmeYourBundle.php
  class AcmeYourBundle extends Bundle
  {
      public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
      {
          parent::build($container);

          $container->addCompilerPass(new ParametersCompilerPass(), PassConfig::TYPE_AFTER_REMOVING);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, i will get back to you

Comment: After adding the build function i got the error `Attempted to load class "ParametersCompilerPass" from namespace "ClickTeck\featuresBundle". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?` so I added `use` statement and pointed to `ParametersCompilerPass()` which leads me to another error of `The autoloader expected class "ClickTeck\featuresBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ParametersCompilerPass" to be defined in file "/opt/lampp/htdocs/services/src/ClickTeck/featuresBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ParametersCompilerPass.php"`.

Comment: The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.` and i cant seem to understand where is the type, i have crossed checked the name of files and class

Comment: I think that you could forget to add `namespace ClickTeck\featuresBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;` in the CompilerPass class. Read the documentation about autoloading in symfony and composer... and about namespaces.

Comment: thanks, that make the error go away, i am new to symfony and still trying to get my head around it. Do i need to add something in services.yml because my IDE is saying missing service for `$em = $container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');`

Comment: No. It is already set in `Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension` it is just alias to the entity manager service that you defined in config.

Comment: something else is wrong then because i get the error `[ReflectionException] Class  does not exist  `

Comment: What class does not exist? Try to remove your cache manually and then test your controller.

Comment: yes thats the first thing i tried, clearing cache, when i got the error of `[ReflectionException] Class does not exist` but that did not fix the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71858/discussion-between-baig-and-michael-sivolobov).

Comment: If you do change on database the parameter is not changing because of container cached, any solution for this issue?

Comment: Clear the cache when updating your Settings entity

Comment: Many thanks for this @MichaelSivolobov! Do you know if it is possible to access the '@request_stack' within this compiler pass without using $_SERVER? Would be interesting for me. I want to load parameters by hostname so that I can have multiple environments at one place. :-)

Comment: Hmm its a nice idea but if you modify `mailer_transport` with that for example it will not work :-(

Comment: Take care!  You should not get a service instance during the container building phase because the service configuration completion is not guarantee at this time. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18673#issuecomment-216183042

Comment: @Tsounabe, thank you for your notice. This solution is tested for doctrine only and it works. I investigated the way how doctrine service get initialised and in the `TYPE_AFTER_REMOVING` part of container compilation we already have doctrine service initialised.

Comment: this doesn't work in the twig.yaml file... `param_name: '%param_name%'` says I  have requested a non-existent parameter "param_name"... Any idea? (getParameter() in the controller works)

Answer (score 2):

The solution with `CompilerPass` didn't work in my case in Symfony 4, it worked only from the controller but not when used in the twig.yaml file:

```
param_name: '%param_name%'
```

Since I need to use this parameter in the sidebar, so in all the pages, passing it from the controller is not feasible.

This is what I did, thanks to the fact that you can [reference services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html#referencing-services) as global Twig variables.

I have a service, called Settings, that loads the settings directly from the database, simplified:

```
class Settings
{
    private Connection $db;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->db = $this->em->getConnection();
    }

    /**
     * Get a setting value. 
     * If the setting doesn't exist, return the default value specified as the second param
     */
    public function get(string $name, $default=''): string
    {
        $val = $this->db->executeQuery("SELECT `value` FROM `settings` WHERE `key`=?;", [$name])->fetchOne();
        // strict comparison is needed for cases when $val === '0'
        return $val !== false ? $val : $default;
    }

    /**
     * Set a setting value. 
     * If the setting doesn't exist, create it. Otherwise, replace the db value
     */
    public function set(string $name, ?string $value, string $description = '')
    {
        if(is_null($value)) {
            // Remove the key
            $this->db->executeQuery('DELETE FROM settings WHERE `key`=?;', [$name]);
            return;
        }

        $this->db->executeQuery('INSERT INTO settings (`key`, `type`, `value`, `description`) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `type`=?, `value`=?, `description`=?;',
            [$name, $type, $value, $description, $type, $value, $description]);
    }
```

Now, I simply added in `config/packages/twig.yaml`:

```
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        # ...
        settings: '@App\Service\Settings'
```

This is amazing because now I can read any db setting from any template:

```
{{ dump(settings.get('setting_name')) }}
```

The Settings class I posted is simplified, it can still be improved for example to avoid making the same query again if you request the same setting more than once, but that's trivial to do (store the fetched keys in a `private $fetched` array), or a `warmup(array $keys)` method to fetch many settings with a single query (`"SELECT key, value FROM settings WHERE key IN (?);", [$toFetch], [Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY]`)