# Symfony prependExtensionConfig with data from a service

Tags: symfony, config

I try to prepend a config array to a different bundle using the prependExtensionConfig from my bundle. All works fine until $config is hardcoded.

My goal is to load the $config values using a **service** (from the db for example) and than prepend it to the other bundle.

The problem is that the services are not loaded at that moment.
I guess this is a limitation is symfony2.

Any ideas? thx

```
    class MyExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {   
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {   

        $config = // load config from a service ...

        $container->prependExtensionConfig('other_bundle', $config);
    }   
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load Symfony's config parameters from database (Doctrine)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713495/how-to-load-symfonys-config-parameters-from-database-doctrine)

Comment: The prepend method is called before load in the extension so the services are not loaded at that moment. Setting a parameter does not help.

Comment: Did you read the question I linked? I can explain there again the same situation. But it will duplicate answer from linked question.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but if I understand things right prependExtensionConfig and setParameter are different things. Tried it and does not work because of the loading order. I guess it's a limitation and i have to build around it.

Comment: Ok. I will answer your question later...

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to set up your config to take values from parameters section of Service container:

- Setup **config.yml**:

  ```
  # app/config/config.yml
  namespace:
    subnamespace:
      param1: %param1%
      param2: %param2%
  ```

Then you need to fill `%param1%` and `%param2%` parameters in container with values from database. To do that you need to declare your CompilerPass and add it to the container. After whole container will be loaded (in the compile time) you will have access to all services in it.

Just get the entity manager service and query for needed parameters and register them in container.

- Define Compiler pass:

  ```
  # src/Acme/YourBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ParametersCompilerPass.php
  class ParametersCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
  {
      public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
      {
          $em = $container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
          $param1 = $em->getRepository('Acme:Params')->find(1);
          $param2 = $em->getRepository('Acme:Params')->find(2);
          $container->setParameter('param1', $param1);
          $container->setParameter('param2', $param2);
      }
  }
  ```
- In the bundle definition class you need to add compiler pass to your container

  ```
  # src/Acme/YourBundle/AcmeYourBundle.php
  class AcmeYourBundle extends Bundle
  {
      public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
      {
          parent::build($container);

          $container->addCompilerPass(new ParametersCompilerPass(), PassConfig::TYPE_AFTER_REMOVING);
      }
  }
  ```

  `PassConfig::TYPE_AFTER_REMOVING` means that this CompilerPass will be processed almost after all other compiler passes and in this moment you will already have every service injected.

Comment: Hi Michael, checked it again, but all I got is `[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException].  You have requested a non-existent parameter "param1"`.  By adding some debug it looks like the bundle config file is loaded first (and the exception is thrown) and the compiler pass is executed after (already too late).   Am I omitting something obvious? Cheers

Comment: Try to define "default" values for these params and also try to change priority of compiler pass to process it before your bundle will process parameters.

Comment: Tried it, by adding param1 & param2 null as default, they remain null even after the compiler pass is being executed.  Did this with all the 5 priorities.

Comment: What bundle do you want prepend config to?