# Getting entity manager in CompilerPass class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I've create CompilerPass class to set some data from database as parameters:

```
class ParametersCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $em = $container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
        $params = $em->getRepository(Setting::class)->findAll();
    }
}
```

but I get this error:

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1102] Incorrect database name 'nv_097f203e25c61d94_resolve_database_url_c9a61b2f5dc3b858f85dcd10be22549a'
```

When I get the entity manager e.g. in controller via `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager` service everything works fine.

doctrine.yaml:

```
parameters:
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.4'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load Symfony's parameter with compiler pass from custom service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314240/load-symfonys-parameter-with-compiler-pass-from-custom-service)

Comment: @emix Yes, I saw that before, but the problem is that I can't get default entity manager

Comment: It’s explained there why. Did you try with different order? https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-compiler-passes-improvements

Comment: @emix Yes, I was trying to set various order values, but nothing's changed (except different errors when the values were to small)

Comment: I guess you have to resolve the variables by yourself.

Comment: Your approach doesn’t sound right anyway. You don’t have any control over the hardcoded values in the Symfony application cache. What if a change is made? You are going to clear the cache each time? Better to cache these values inside the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a service at build time in a CompilerPass, the container is not generated yet. A CompilerPass is meant to write things in the generated .php file that will be loaded later.

You probably just want a standard service which loads your configuration in its constructor and provide them through getters.