# How to access doctrine inside the bundle build method

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a build method like the following, Inside the bundle class.

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $em = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
}
```

And I want to access the doctrine to retrieve some data from the database.
But I get an error  `You have requested a non-existent service "doctrine".` And I don't know what to do. I appreciate any help.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382980/load-symfony-5-2-config-from-database/66387406#66387406) is an explanation of why this will not work and a possible alternative approach involving creating your own database connection.  But make sure you understand the pitfalls and limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice, that argument of the `build()` method is of type `ContainerBuilder`.

`ContainerBuilder` is meant to collect information about **service definitions** to allow the actual compilation of the container. Therefore no actual service instances are available in this class. Moreover, it is possible that container itself is not available at all at this stage, for example in the case of a fresh install.

You need to re-consider your decision on the requirement of the Doctrine at this stage. You may post a separate question if you need assistance with finding a better way of implementation of the underlying task which brings you to this question.